# Редакция предложения

Tags: стилистика

Правильно ли здесь расставлены знаки препинания? Больше всего интересуют прописные буквы в скобках... Но также и кавычки...

После успешной защиты кандидатской диссертации я полагал, что наш главный конструктор  назначит меня на начальствующую должность («Плох тот солдат, который не хочет быть генералом» или «Каждый солдат носит в ранце маршальский жезл»), тем более, что в организации всего-то было три кандидата наук…

Может быть, лучше вообще разбить на несколько:

После успешной защиты кандидатской диссертации я полагал, что наш главный конструктор  назначит меня на начальствующую должность. («Плох тот солдат, который не хочет быть генералом»... Или... «Каждый солдат носит в ранце маршальский жезл».) Тем более, что в организации всего-то было три кандидата наук…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Предлагаемый вариант

После успешной защиты кандидатской диссертации я полагал, что наш главный конструктор назначит меня на начальствующую должность («**плох тот солдат, который не хочет быть генералом**» и **«каждый солдат носит в ранце маршальский жезл»**), тем более что в организации всего-то было три кандидата наук…

Вставка заключена в скобки и состоит из двух цитат, связанных союзом И, выбор строчной или прописной буквы свободный, но строчные буквы смотрятся лучше. Разделять текст на части из-за цитат не стоит.

Comment: Да, спасибо. Я вижу, что мой вариант хуже... Самое смешное, что я сначала так и сделала: поменяла на строчные... Но я не знала, что здесь допускаются варианты... Здесь это пословицы, но, наверное, это как с лозунгами... самостоятельные предложения, включаемые в основное в качестве компонентов.

Comment: Эти самостоятельные пословицы можно одну другой усилить: ПРИЧЁМ подойдёт для связки.

Comment: Сама по себе идея интересная... Но не вижу, зачем...